# Sending query through python but rowcount is still 0

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a program which manages communication of insurance renewal payment to the customers.

I have a mysql database containing information about policies of all the customers.

The main aim at this stage of my program is to send a reminder email to the customer 30 days prior to the due date.

Here is the code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
import mysql.connector as mc
from tkinter import*
import datetime

dt=datetime.datetime.today()

number_of_days = {1:31, 2:30, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}

port=465
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = 
"xxxx@xxxx"
receiver_email = ""
password = "xxxx"



mycon=mc.connect(host='localhost',user='xxxx',passwd='xxxx',database='life_insurance_premium_renewal')
cursor=mycon.cursor()

current_year = dt.year
current_month = dt.month
current_day = dt.day

# for 30 days
if number_of_days[dt.month]==31:
    if dt.day + 30 > 31:
        if dt.month!=12:
            req_month=dt.month+1
            req_year=dt.year
            req_day=(dt.day + 30)-(31)

        elif dt.month==12:
            req_month=1
            req_year=dt.year + 1
            req_day=(dt.day + 30)-(31)

    elif dt.day + 30 <= 31:
        req_month=dt.month
        req_year=dt.year
        req_day=dt.day+30

elif number_of_days[dt.month]==30:
    if dt.day + 30 > 30:
        req_month=dt.month + 1
        req_year=dt.year
        req_day=(dt.day + 30)-(30)

    elif dt.day + 30 <= 30:
        req_month=dt.month
        req_year=dt.year
        req_day=dt.day + 30

date="%s-%s-%s"%(req_year, req_month, req_day)
print(date)

cursor.execute("select  policy_number from policy_details where due_date = %s"%(date))


policy_number_data=cursor.fetchall()

recorded_policy_numbers=[]

if cursor.rowcount==0:
    pass

elif cursor.rowcount>0:
    for n in  range(0,cursor.rowcount()):
    
recorded_policy_numbers.append(cursor.fetchone)

 print(cursor.rowcount)

    

for i in range (0,len(recorded_policy_numbers)):
    cursor.execute("select due_date from policy_details where policy_number = %s"%(recorded_policy_numbers[n]))
    due_date=cursor.fetchall()

print(due_date)
```

Below the comment "#30 days" is the program logic to determine the date 30 days from today. That date is stored in the variable "date".

So the program goes to the database, searches for rows with due date same as that of "date" and returns their policy numbers. These policy numbers are appended to an empty list "recorded_policy_numbers". These are going to be the policy numbers to which the email is going to be sent today.

You can see that I have print() statements one for "date" and the other for rowcount to make sure the query has found the matching. I have exactly one row in my database with the same date as given by the "date".

Yet the rowcount comes 0.

Can someone point out where this is going wrong?

Comment: 30 days in February? The number of days in February is very much a function of the year. Also MySql is quite capable of doing date math. Why not just `datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)`? **And do not show your password**

Comment: @Booboo I tried doing the calculation of date simply with datetime, but found that it treats it like numbers...so timedelta will work? I didn't know it...a lot of things is not covered in our school...btw can you point out why the rowcount is 0? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your date calculation is wrong (as I pointed out there are *never* 30 days in February and I then made no effort to try to follow the logic). By the way, if you are doing `policy_number_data=cursor.fetchall()`, you can just use `len(policy_number_data)` to get the number of rows returned, no? Also, see MySql `DATE_ADD` function: `select policy_number from policy_details where due_date = DATE_ADD(today, INTERVAL 30 DAY)`. Just make sure you have the correct session time zone in effect.

Comment: Actually, instead of relying on `rowcount()` try `len(records_fetched)`

Comment: I meant `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: @Booboo there is also `DATEDIFF(curdate(),estimated_date)` right? the `estiamted_date` to be the current_date + 30

Comment: @CoolCloud I think you just invented `estiamted_date` (there is no such variable). Same goes for `records_fetched`.

Comment: @Booboo i was on an assumption there is something like `estimated_date` with the OP

Comment: @Booboo so are you saying that the query has been passed successfully, only that the rowcount is false?

Comment: No, the rowcount *should* be accurate. I am just saying there is another, more direct way. Those are the actual rows returned.

Comment: @Booboo I did what you said...replaced the rowcount with len...but now it is showing that 5here is a mysql error in the line:                               cursor.execute("select  policy_number from policy_details where due_date = %s"%(date))

Comment: @Booboo I ran query alone in mysql and it worked...it returned me the matching row...but the python program is saying there is a mysql sync error

Comment: You need to update your question with all your error messages and stack traces and updated code. Let me know when you have done this.

Comment: @Booboo After some more code editing I finally got it...all thanks to you Booboo. Thank you so much to all.